# Change a variable in stateful widget when function is called in modalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a homepage , a Stateful Widget and a modalBottomSheet.
When I press a button in modalBottomSheet, I want to change a variable in Stateful Widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String variable;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Show Modal Bottom Sheet'),
        onPressed: (){
          showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context){
                    return Container(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Change Variable in ListWidget'),
                        onPressed: (){
                          /// ??
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                );
        },
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return ListWidget();
          },
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When the button is pressed in the modalBottomSheet, I want to assign new value to this variable in this ListWidget.

```
class ListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListWidgetState createState() => _ListWidgetState();
}

class _ListWidgetState extends State<ListWidget> {

  String variable = 'Old Value';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(variable),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass value to your second class file using a variable and change the value of that variable in your main class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String variable;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Show Modal Bottom Sheet'),
        onPressed: (){
          showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context){
                    return Container(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Change Variable in ListWidget'),
                        onPressed: (){
                          variable = "new Value";
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                );
        },
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return ListWidget(variable : variable);
          },
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

class file 2 code

```
class ListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  String variable;
  ListWidget({this.variable='Old Value'});
  @override
  _ListWidgetState createState() => _ListWidgetState(variable:this.variable);
}

class _ListWidgetState extends State<ListWidget> {

  String variable = 'Old Value';
  _ListWidgetState({this.variable});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(variable),
    );
  }
}
```